# Laravel 5 bulk insert with relations

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel, laravel-5

I need to bulk insert lots of data to mysql. Around 500k rows, with relations (hard part) in Laravel 5.3

Tables are vehicles, users and user_vehicle

Plain vehicles insertion array looks something like this:

```
$vehicles = array();
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $temp = array(
        'license_plate' => $val->license_plate,
        'created_at' => $now,
        'updated_at' => $now,
        'state_id' => $activeState,
        'type_id' => $typeId,
    );

    array_push($vehicles, $temp);
}
```

I can successfully insert records like this:

```
$vehicles = array_chunk($vehicles, 10000);

foreach ($vehicles as $key => $vehicle) {
    Vehicle::insert($vehicle);
}
```

It takes some seconds to insert all that data and everything works, but now I need to add relations to them.
Since one vehicle can belong to many users (owner, driver etc) then I need to attach certain user to certain vehicle.

Now, when I try to add relations here's where I'm stuck:

```
$vehicles = array();
$vehUsers = array();

$users = Users::get();

foreach ($data as $val) {
    // Remap data to right structure
    $temp = array(
        'license_plate' => $val->license_plate,
        'created_at' => $now,
        'updated_at' => $now,
        'state_id' => $activeState,
        'type_id' => $typeId,
    );

    // Search for right user (This part is really slow)
    $userId = $users->where('email', $val->email)->first();
    if ($userId) {
        $userId = $userId->id;
    }

    array_push($vehicles, $temp);

    // Thought that it might help to save them into array for later use
    array_push($vehUsers, $userId);
}
```

But the problem is, that I can't insert them like this

```
$vehicles = array_chunk($vehicles, 10000);

foreach ($vehicles as $key => $vehicle) {
    Vehicle::insert($vehicle);
    // Need to attach user here somehow
}
```

And I need to run them in bulks (10k in my case) becouse 1 by 1 insertion takes too long

```
// Insert them and relations one by one and it will take years
foreach ($vehicles as $key => $vehicle) {
    $veh = Vehicle::insert($vehicle);
    $veh->users()->attach($vehUsers[$key]);
}
```

How can I bulk insert vehicles and their relations?

**EDIT:** Slow part is doing DB queries. I can wait 10-20 sec for php to finish looping over items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load all users. But select only `id` and `email`:

```
$users = User::pluck('email', 'id')->toArray();
```

This will create an array with `[id => email]` structure.

Then you'll be able to work with this array without executing additional queries:

```
$userId = $users[$email];
```

Then add an `id` column of `bigint` type to `vehicle_user` pivot table. Create separate chunk array for this table and use bulk insert of relations instead of using `attach()` method.

Comment: Thanks for first part of code. it really made thing faster =) And direct add to vehicle_user with DB::insert(bulk_data) works. Just had to figure how to get vehicle ids from first bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please understand that the technique you are following is making you loop through `$data` (which is really really large) again and again. Why? Because...

1. First for loop for making a temporary variable.
2. Then second for loop for inserting chunked data.
3. Third for loop for find User with same email as input and then selecting the Vehicle of that same user and then attaching syncing it with `$user->vehicles()->sync([...Vehicle Ids...]);`

By making only one loop for everything you can simply get your thing done by

```
foreach($data as $key => $vehicle) {
  $vehicle = Vehicle::create([
                      'license_plate' => $vehicle->license_plate,
                      'state_id' => $activeState,
                      'type_id' => $typeId,
                    ]);

  $user = User::where('email', $vehicle->email)->first();

  $vehicle->users()->attach([$user->id]);
}
```

Please understand that BelongsToMany method doesn't really have its own Model, but for such/one time cases... You can try and make a the Pivot Table Model and then process your query as well. But the again, something like `Vehicle::where('license_plate', $val->license_plate)` might still be required.... Which is again useless.

**Note:- You can either perform 3 queries in one for loop. Or 3 for loops with multiple queries. I would definitely prefer the first one here**.

Comment: **1)** Running through first loop takes about 5-10 sec, 
**2)** Inserting chunked data takes only some seconds
Running DB queries are really slow. While loop inserting them it takes about 20 min. And it's a lot faster to save all users before looping into variable, than asking them from DB for each circle. Think I have to use raw sql here :/

Comment: Yes, it ran for 15 minutes and ended with timeout